# nginx - Takes too long for a connection to be established

Tags: nginx, file-sharing, video-streaming

I am new to nginx, and I am using it currently on my server to serve videos to users. a few days ago the server started becoming extremely slow while have around 500-600 users online, note that I have a 1gbps line on the server so its not the bandwidth. it takes the server around a minute or 2 to respond but once the file starts streaming the speed is decent, so its taking the server long to spot the file I guess! I was wondering if anyone knows how I can fix this? I have already tried increasing the open file limit and worker limit, but still not luck!!!

I am also interested to hire someone to fix this for me if they know how to do it exactly and have previous experience with a similar situation.

Regards

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

```
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7861       7695        166          0          3       4233
-/+ buffers/cache:       3459       4402
Swap:         4095         44       4051
```

Comment: Do you have any performance metrics graphed or stored? Cpu, i/o wait, ram usage etc.

Comment: unfortunately I do not have a control panel on the server to graph anything!!

Comment: I added the memory usage

Comment: video files are served from local disk? If so, i/o is highly relevant.

Comment: they are, but to be honest I am not sure how to get the i/o via ssh!! it would be helpful if you could help me out there too.

Answer (score 2):

So, you need to work from the bottom-up to find the bottleneck.  I wrote a fairly comprehensive article on [finding performance bottlenecks](http://forms.anchor.com.au/hosting/development/HuntingThePerformanceWumpus) a couple of years ago, which should be helpful.

In short, you need to identify the exact system component that's the source of the problem (using tools like `sar` or it's many equivalents), then fix it.  Once you fix that, something else will become the bottleneck, so you repeat the process until performance is acceptable.

In your specific case, disk I/O *might* be the problem, but the complicating factor is the fact that it takes a long time for requests to be serviced but they stream OK.  I'd be looking into where the holdup there is -- is the kernel establishing the TCP connection quickly (look for the three-way-handshake with `tcpdump`), is nginx getting an `accept` through quickly (`strace` nginx and it's workers), is the HTTP request processing taking a while (`nginx` log files at maximum debug, cap'n)?  A methodical approach to problem-solving will cure many ills.

(As an aside, whilst I don't do consulting, I do work for a hosting company that specialises in full-stack system support, so if you need paid help, it's always there)

Comment: hey, how can I contact you?

Comment: I don't do private support; my employer's details are linked to from my profile if that's what you're after.

Comment: Link to the article is broken. Could you update it?